# Javascript images not being displayed in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I am new to javascript and trying to display an image in a new window.
The code is -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc(){
        var new_window = window.open();
        var doc = new_window.document;
        var image = document.createElement('img');
        image.setAttribute('src','imagepath');
        image.setAttribute('alt',"image");
        doc.appendChild(image);
    }
</script>
```

This image is not being displayed in FireFox and Chrome while 'alt' text is displayed. While in IE nothing is being displayed. Kindly help.

Comment: I assume imagepath actually points to an image? And that you are calling `myfunc()` at some point?

Comment: What is the actual imagepath? It could be a absolute/relative issue.

Comment: @andrewb:imagepath can be either relative or absolute. It is generated dynamically.

Comment: @Jivings:It is being called from onclick of a button in html file

Comment: Can you please post the actual code of the imagepath? If this is the actual code, then all your images are exactly this: `<img src="imagepath" alt="image"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps !!

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VxvgF/)

```
<button>Working !!</button>

$('button').off('click').on('click', function(){
        var new_window = window.open();
        var doc = new_window.document.body;
        var image = document.createElement('img');
        doc.appendChild(image);        
       $(doc).find('img').attr({
        src: "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/276993_573451729347425_460197233_q.jpg",
             title: "Image" 
});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't insert a node into the `document`, you need to specify the `body`:

```
var doc = new_window.document.body;
```

It works fine for me with that correction.

Comment: He mentions that the alt text appears.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos True... Then it doesn't work at all for me in FF and Chrome. I get `HierarchyRequestError: A Node was inserted somewhere it doesn't belong.`

Comment: I didn't say I disagree (I would have downvoted in that case). I just think it is not the *main* problem in this actual case.

Answer (score 0):

what i found is that dosent works nor newer versions ...

try this

```
var img = new Image(1,1); //width, height values are optional parameter acc to your requirments

img.src = 'your image url';
```

hope this will work

it worked for me in chrome
not tested in firefox
but i think it will work in firefox aswell.